# How to make class A convertible to class B

Tags: c++, constructor, type-conversion, c++20

Here are two basically unrelated classes:

```
class A {};

class B {};
```

And the concept checking the convertibility of those two `A` and `B` classes:

```
template<typename FROM, typename TO>
concept SafelyConvertible = 
    is_convertible<typename FROM::pointer, typename TO::pointer>::value &&
    !is_array<typename TO::element_type>::value
;
```

FROM and TO in above SafelyConvertible concept is expected to be custom smart pointer implementation providing the pointer typedef:

```
template<typename T>
class smart_ptr {
    using pointer = T*;
...
};
```

The goal is simply to make the `A` convertible to `B` so that the concept `SafelyConvertible` is evaluated to `true`.

I tried to implement the converting constructor in B:

```
class B {
    B( const A & other ) { ... }

    B( A && other ) { ... }
};
```

but somehow it did not make the `A` convertible to `B`... Thanks in advance to anyone willing to help

Comment: You are trying to check whether `A*` can be converted to `B*` and not whether `A` can be converted to `B` so the copy constructor is actually useless here. C++ does not implicitly allow pointers of different types to be converted to one another.

Comment: @Ruks - ok, so how to make the pointers explicitly convertible? Any hint?

Comment: To make pointers convertible you need some inheritance relation between `A` and `B`.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to check whether `A*` can be converted to `B*` and not whether `A` can be converted to `B` so the copy constructor and move constructor are actually useless in this case. C++ does not implicitly allow pointers of different types to be converted to one another.

Pointers of two classes are only implicitly convertible when one of them is derived from the other, i.e.:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

class A {};
class B : public A {};

int main()
{
    static_assert(std::is_convertible_v<B*, A*>, "ERROR"); // OK
    static_assert(std::is_convertible_v<A*, B*>, "ERROR"); // ERROR
}
```

Or:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

class B {};
class A : public B {};

int main()
{
    static_assert(std::is_convertible_v<B*, A*>, "ERROR"); // ERROR
    static_assert(std::is_convertible_v<A*, B*>, "ERROR"); // OK
}
```

Alternatively, you could fetch the types from their pointer counterparts using [`std::remove_pointer`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_pointer):

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

// ...

template<typename FROM, typename TO>
concept SafelyConvertible = 
    is_convertible_v<std::remove_pointer_t<typename FROM::pointer>, std::remove_pointer_t<typename TO::pointer>> &&
    !is_array_v<typename TO::element_type>;

// ...
```

Comment: Or to use directly the types without extracting them from the FROM and TO respectively?

Comment: @MartinKopecký Why are you talking about pointers to begin with? If `A` and `B` are unrelated types, you can't store a smart pointer to one of them in a smart pointer to the other.

Comment: C++ does allow pointers of different types to be converted to each other, just not of two unrelated classes

Answer (score 0):

is_convertible<FROM,TO> return true if the FROM could be implicitly covert to TO. This conversion is possible if and only if TO can be  copy-initialized from FROM in other words if

```
    TO to = from;// (type FROM)
```

this statement is compiled successfully so these objects are convertible. Otherwise this conversion is impossible.